# Moving from LINQ2SQL to LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF 4.1 in POCO mode.

LINQ2SQL generates partial methods on the datacontext that get called when inserting/updated/deleting an entity.  They're helpful for cases like:

```
    partial void InsertCampaign( Campaign instance )
    {
        instance.CreatedAtUTC = instance.ModifiedAtUTC = DateTime.UtcNow;

        ExecuteDynamicInsert( instance );
    }

    partial void UpdateCampaign( Campaign instance )
    {
        instance.ModifiedAtUTC = DateTime.UtcNow;

        ExecuteDynamicUpdate( instance );
    }
```

So, my question is -- with EF, how do you hook into the inserting/updating/deleting of entities so that you can perform operations such as the above?  I would prefer not to have to do this manually every time I create/update an entity.

Thank you

Comment: What "flavor" of 4.1 are you using, code-, model- or db-first?  Are you asking how to generate or have EF generate your DbContext?

Comment: @Marc L -- I'm using db-first.  I've already generated POCO classes and have done several EF projects already.  I've just never learned how to automatically apply values when inserting/updating like you can do easily in LINQ2SQL.  Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override SaveChanges() method in your DbContext and do something like:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var modified = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
        // set whatever values you want on modified entities
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```